# Inherited singleton in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, singleton

Could you please check out this piece of code:

```
#include <vector>
class A
{
public:
    A(int a, int b);
};

class C :public A
{
public:
    C(int a, int b):A(a,b){}
    static C instances;
};

C C::instances;

int main()
{
    return 1;
}
```

The compilation gives me error as:

```
$ c++ inheritance.cpp 
inheritance.cpp:16:6: error: no matching function for call to ‘C::C()’
inheritance.cpp:16:6: note: candidates are:
inheritance.cpp:12:2: note: C::C(int, int)
inheritance.cpp:12:2: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
inheritance.cpp:8:7: note: C::C(const C&)
inheritance.cpp:8:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

I need C to inherit from A and I need A to have arguments in its constructor.
Finally, I need the instance's static variable to be declared and defined with no arguments. 
So is there a solution to that? I value your kind comments.

Another point to note:
if the static variable was a container, like:

> static std::vector instances;

the code would compile just fine. Why?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for all the answers,
but, if I modify `C C::instances;` to `C C::instances(0,0);` i will get another error:
$ c++ inheritance.cpp 
/tmp/cctw6l67.o: In function `C::C(int, int)':
inheritance.cpp:(.text._ZN1CC2Eii[_ZN1CC5Eii]+0x1b): undefined reference to`A::A(int, int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

any idea why? and how to fix it?

thanks

Comment: you may need to define a default constructor.

Comment: You want `C` to only have the two-argument constructor, and also be able to construct it with no arguments? Those two objectives are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @samy.vilar if I define a default constructor for C, I will not be able to supply arguments to A(base class). also, A cannot have another constructor.

Comment: @rahman I see than you can use any of the following answers, wanted to post one but their all good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define a constructor, the compiler no longer generates a default one for you, which you attempt to call with `C C::instances;`. You can bypass this by calling the available constructor:

```
C C::instances(0,0);
```

or provide a default constructor for `C`.

With

```
static std::vector<C> instances;
```

it compiles because no elements are created, and `std::vector` has a default constructor which initializes an empty vector. But

```
C::instances.push_back(C());
```

wouldn't compile.

Comment: wait wait, C C::instances(0,0); gives another error:  c++ inheritance.cpp 
/tmp/cctw6l67.o: In function `C::C(int, int)':
inheritance.cpp:(.text._ZN1CC2Eii[_ZN1CC5Eii]+0x1b): undefined reference to `A::A(int, int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You have to define the constructor for A also `A(int a, int b){};`. Now it should compile.

Answer (score 1):

With `C C::instances;` you are constructing an object, therefore calling its constructor.

Since you provided a constructor with two arguments `C(int a, int b)`, the default constructor (which requires none) is not generated automatically for you any more. So you'd have to create instaces either with 2 parameters `C C::instances(0, 0)` or alternatively provide an additional default constructor for C:

```
C() : A(0, 0)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On your first question: you're getting this error since the line

```
C C::instances;
```

attempts to call a `C` constructor which takes no argument (i.e. `C::C()`). You could either fix this by introducing a `C::C()` constructor which calls `A::A(int, int)` with two default values, or you specify default values for the existing constructor, e.g.

```
C::C(int a = 0, int b = 0) : A(a, b) {}
```

On your second question: a `std::vector` has a default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`C C::instances;`

This would try to call the default constructor and compiler will not provide one since you provided a constructor.

Add default constructor to `class A` and `class C`

```
class A
{
public:
   A(int a, int b);
   A() {}  // implement default constructor
 };

//class C
 class C :public A
 {
 public :

    C(int a, int b):A(a,b){}
     C() {} // default constructor
     static C instances;
  };
```

`static std::vector instances;`

This will work because `std::vector` has a default constructor.